# Global favicon.ico and iOS icons

Tags: ios, nginx, favicon

I am looking to set the icons for a domain on an nginx server I have configured.  There are many different urls on this domain which will need to display the same favicon / icon no matter what the url.

I am looking for some advice in implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you would like to have all (sub)domains on a server have the same favicon, you can enter this in the server configuration:

```
location ~ /(favicon.ico|apple-touch-icon.png)$ {
    root /var/www/default;
}
```

And just place the icons in the above folder.

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: This works for me after replacing squiggles with parenthesis.

Comment: You could set the preceding “~*” modifier for case-insensitive matching, and cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for either these two HTML tags:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="somepath/image.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

or these two domain-root-folder files:

```
apple-touch-icon.png
favicon.ico
```

as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility) (with more details). You can also use apple-touch-icon-precomposed if you don't want Apple's standard icon gloss.

Since you want every page to have the same icon, putting them in the root without bothering with HTML is probably simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Janardan but this is NGINX specific and I would like to force it for every url on the server.